# Bible interpretation and hermeneutical approaches

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

I have suggested [on Meta previously](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3865/6071) that [bible-interpretation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible-interpretation) should be a synonym of [exegesis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exegesis). The problem was that not everything with the first tag should have the second instead.

But from looking at BH I've had a new idea: we should borrow their tag [hermeneutical-approaches](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutical-approaches). [bible-interpretation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible-interpretation) should still be made a synonym of [exegesis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exegesis), because I think it is more often misused than used correctly, but the others can move to [hermeneutical-approaches](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutical-approaches). (There are some that should be retagged to [biblical-basis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblical-basis) instead.)

Here are some questions I think would be appropriately tagged as [hermeneutical-approaches](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutical-approaches):

- [What is the difference between 'Biblical' and 'Systematic' theology?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4000/6071)
- [If you don't believe in the inerrancy of scripture, on what basis can you interpret scripture?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/17807/6071)
- [For Eastern Orthodox churches, what are the main references concerning Biblical Interpretation methodology?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/19132/6071)
- [Interpreting the Bible as a cultural piece of literature?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/24251/6071)
- and maybe [Has the Church historically considered biblical texts concerning slavery to be transcultural or finite?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/14361/6071)

Comment: If you don't like this suggestion, can you explain why?

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: hermeneutical-approaches implies to me that the question is *about* how to do hermeneutics or the validity of some approach. I don't see that as synonymous to exegesis.

Comment: @fredsbendtheGrinch So you're agreeing?

Comment: I think I was implying that "hermemeutical-approaches" is off-topic on this site.

Comment: @fredsbendtheGrinch See my edit for a few questions I think would be appropriately tagged with hermemeutical-approaches.

Comment: The first three, yes that makes some sense. I think the fourth should maybe be closed as primarily opinion based. I see the 5th as needing the exegesis tag (it has bible-interpretation), but not the hermeneutical-approaches tag.